# webFrame Context in electronjs

Tags: electron

Is there a way to get `webFrame` context to inject chrome-api, like electron does for webContents (or renderer process) in file `lib/renderer/content-script-injector.js` line number of the function *14* in electronjs version *3.0.14*.

The following code is extract from electron repo. runInThisContext is 'vm' import and seems to run on rederer process of electron.

```
// Run the code with chrome API integrated.
const runContentScript = function(extensionId, url, code) {
  const context = {};
  require('./chrome-api').injectTo(extensionId, false, context);
  const wrapper = `((chrome) => {\n  ${code}\n  })`;
  const compiledWrapper = runInThisContext(wrapper, {
    filename: url,
    lineOffset: 1,
    displayErrors: true
  });
  return compiledWrapper.call(this, context.chrome);
};
```